# Can we run a batch file from Vector canoe

Tags: batch-file, canoe

Is there any possibility to run a batch file from vector canoe?
If so, I need to run a batch file from Canoe which will trigger a python script and start executing it.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can run batch file using sysExec() and sysExecCmd().

Functions Prototype:

```
long sysExec(char cmd[], char params[]);
long sysExec(char cmd[], char params[], char directory[]); // form 2
long sysExecCmd(char cmd[], char params[]);
long sysExecCmd(char cmd[], char params[], char directory[]); // form 2
```

Example 1:

```
sysExec("C:\\Program Files\\Beyond Compare 3\\BCompare.EXE", Commandline, "C:\\Program Files\\Beyond Compare 3");
```

Example 2:

```
char configDir[1024];
getAbsFilePath("", configDir, elcount(configDir)); 
sysExecCmd("dir", "/O:-D", configDir); // show files in configuration directory, newest files first
```